# Show login component on route, but also if user is not present

Tags: reactjs

I have an App component which shows my login component on /login route and also displays another compnent when the user is not authenticated.

```
<div className="App">
    <Router>
        {this.state.isAuth && <ChatUsersList setChatList={chatList => (this.chatList = chatList)} setCurrentChat={this.setCurrentChat} setUserChats={this.setUserChats} chats={this.state.filteredChats} />}
        <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login setUser={this.setUser} />} />                               
    </Router>
</div>
```

But I also want to display the login user when the user is not authenticated. Should I just add another case with my Login:

```
{!this.state.isAuth && <Login>}
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you pass isAuth in the same login Route and let Login do the check how it should behave based on isAuth value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a separate wrapper component to encapsulate routing logic.

For example

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function AuthorizedRoute({ path, component, isAuth }) {
  if (isAuth) {
    return <Route path={path} component={component} />;
  } else {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
}
```

And use it in your App component like this

```
...
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login setUser={this.setUser} />} />
    <AuthorizedRoute
      path="/your-new-path"
      component={YourNewComponent}
      isAuth={this.state.isAuth}
    />
  </Router>
</div>;
...
```